# STDERR redirection to log file breaks on log file deletion

Tags: c, redirect, stderr

Have a server code developed in C that runs in unix environment , the server redirects STDOUT/STDERR to a log as follows

```
static gboolean
create_log_file (const char *log_file)
{
  int log_file_fd;

  g_return_val_if_fail (log_file != NULL, FALSE);

  log_file_fd = open (log_file, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0644);

  if (log_file_fd < 0)
    {
      return FALSE;
    }

  dup2 (log_file_fd, 1);
  dup2 (log_file_fd, 2);

  close (log_file_fd);

  return TRUE;
}
```

planning to setup a archive/purge cron for this log file , to ensure that disk usage is within limits.

The logging works perfectly fine , untill the purge cron kicks-in and deletes the logfile.

Observe that post log file deletion by the cron run , the STDERR traces stops and the file is no more created ?

Comment: The prints to STDERR by server used to appear in the log file perfectly fine , untill i delete the log file.Post this none of the prints to STDERR appears in the log file ? Note that the server was running and continue to run , when the file was deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Once opened, a file descriptor retains its association with the file that was designated by the name you passed to `open(2)` at the point of the function call. If you later delete the file from the disk, you *unlink* it from that name, but the file persists until all references to it have vanished.

After you delete the file, your program is the only remaining holder of a reference. The program will continue to write into the file, but you can no longer name that file. There are security reasons why the kernel actually does not *want* you to be able to reobtain a name for such delinquent files, and you can't get them back without modifying your OS (there's a Linux kernel module that enables such zombie resurrection, but I doubt Windows has something comparable). When your program ends, the file is finally deleted for good.

Comment: Thanks Kerrek , what do you advice so that cron archives the logs , and purges the file while server prints to STDERR continues to be seen in the log file.

Comment: @sashidharballagiri: You could close and reopen the file every time you log, or log to an internal buffer and flush the log in like manner.

Comment: Or design your application to respond to a specific signal by closing and re-opening the file, which is a fairly common *nix-ish pattern.

Comment: Thanks Kerrek/Twalberg , will try the suggestion.